Compilation works on Cython 0.29, but not Cython 3.0
The project rtmidi-python compiles well on Cython 0.29.37 (the latest version before Cython 3.0), but it fails on Cython 3.0, with the error below.
Are there known incompatibilities when upgrading to Cython 3?
If so, is there a flag to use when calling Cython 3 to keep backwards compatibility with previous versions, without requiring to modify the actual .pyx file?
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
                self.thisptr.cancelCallback()

            self.py_callback = callback

            if self.py_callback is not None:
                self.thisptr.setCallback(midi_in_callback, <void*>self.py_callback)
                                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

rtmidi_python.pyx:92:41: Cannot assign type 'void (double, vector[unsigned char] *, void *) except * nogil' to 'RtMidiCallback' (alias of 'void (*)(double, vector[unsigned char] *, void *) noexcept'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'midi_in_callback'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
...


Did you try adding noexcept to the type of midi_in_callback?

For compatibility with previous versions @l'L'l, I would prefer, first and if possible, to not modify the .pyx code at all, but just pass a flag during build to signify I'd like to keep compatibility with Cython < 3.0

Is self.thisptr.cancelCallback() actually indented as posted?

@PeterMortensen I suspect it probably is. It's a truncated snippet of code from an error report so it's probably just the end of a previous indented block


If so, is there a flag to use when calling Cython 3 to keep backwards compatibility with previous versions, without requiring to modify the actual .pyx file?

legacy_implicit_noexcept
https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html

Are there known incompatibilities when upgrading to Cython 3?

Yes. Cython 3 makes a number of breaking changes. Some of the bigger ones are documented in https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/migrating_to_cy30.html. noexcept is probably the most significant one (both in terms of the intended change, and various unintended edge cases).

Thanks a lot @DavidW! If you have a few more seconds, would you know how I can enable this flag in the context of this setup.py: github.com/superquadratic/rtmidi-python/blob/master/setup.py ? Thanks in advance!

See this section

Thanks @DavidW, but unfortunately, here the only thing imported regarding Cython is this: https://github.com/superquadratic/rtmidi-python/blob/master/setup.py#L5 (from Cython.Distutils import build_ext), there is no line about cythonize, etc. Do you see how to do it, in this context?

I don't immediately know I'm afraid. You might be able to put cythonize round rtmidi_module but that's a guess rather than something I've tested
